# Race Condition in Chrome/FF

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Earlier I submitted a thread where I was trying to implement the below atdmt.com pixel to fire off on the click of a link:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" onclick="javascript:img1=new Image(); img1.src='http://sact.atdmt.com/action/adofat_ImageTest27_1'; img1.height='1'; img1.width='1';">test</a>
```

The pixel is a 1x1 image used to record activity in our system. This works in IE but not Chrome and Firefox. I think the landing page URL (google.com) is loading too quickly and the image (sact.atdmt.com) is not having enough chance to load. I am using chrome dev tools / Fiddler to check to see if the tag is firing.

Someone suggested the below fix:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" onclick="javascript:img1=new Image(); img1.src='http://sact.atdmt.com/action/adofat_ImageTest27_1'; img1.height='1'; img1.width='1'; return false;">test</a>
```

But this does not resolve the actual URL (although the pixel fires, nothing happens when you click on the link).

Another user suggested using an eventlistener instead of onclick attribute, but this still does not fire off the pixel when I click on the link.

```
 <script>
function imageClickHandler(){
var img1;
var img1=new Image();
img1.src='http://sact.atdmt.com/action/adofat_ImageTest27_1';
img1.height='1';
img1.width='1';
}//end function

document.getElementByID("TheExampleLink").addEventListener("click",imageClickHandler,false);
</script>

<a href="http://www.google.com/" id="TheExampleLink">test</a>
```

Ideally, the pixel (jact.atdmt.com) should then fire off and then I should be brought to http://www.google.com ... but the pixel isn't always firing off because of the race condition I mentioned earlier.

Are there any suggestions for how to fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: You might be able to do this with a synchronous ajax request (though you will have to abide by the same-origin policy)

Answer (score 1):

In your last referenced suggestion 
Try this:

```
setTimeOut(imageClickHandler(), 0);
```

If this doesn't work,

try this -

```
<script>

function imageClickHandler(){ 
var img1; 
var img1=new Image();
img1.src='http://sact.atdmt.com/action/adofat_ImageTest27_1';
img1.height='1'; 
img1.width='1'; 
setTimeout(function(){window.location.href='www.google.com'},5000);
}//end function

    document.getElementByID("TheExampleLink").addEventListener("click",imageClickHandler,false);
```

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="TheExampleLink">test</a>
```

Comment: setTimeout with 0 ms is equivalent to yield method in java. It basically let other things happen before executing

Comment: Never heard of time slicing model

Comment: Sometimes, it takes more than that to know the correct work arounds ;-)

Comment: WOW.. You are the Mr. Know it all.. Kudos :P